# Do eiruvs have to be physical?

Tags: eruv-chatzerot

I go by a couple of synagoges on the way to work and I notice signs on the telephone poles saying "End of eiruv". Looking around, I don't see any lines that would form a closed space. I had been given the impression there had to be a physical line to mark the space. Is this correct?

Comment: It is common to use transparent fishing wire made of nylon from the top of one pole to the other and that can be very difficult to see

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, an *eruv* boundary must be physical, though gaps are allowed to an extent. You said the signs were on telephone poles: likely, the telephone poles and wires themselves (or possibly other, tauter wires attached to the poles) served as part of the *eruv* boundary.

Comment: It's also possible the signs were placed a bit inward of the boundary to prevent mistakes.